# Visual Studio C++ - Unable to output a preprocessed file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, preprocessor-directive

I am trying to visualize my source code preprocessed in Visual Studio, but I can't get to output anything. No error, but not any .i file in the end either.

I have seen these options for `cl.exe` here: [How do I see a C/C++ source file after preprocessing in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/how-do-i-see-a-c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing-in-visual-studio)

used `/P`, but after compile, their is nothing more in my project directory or subfolders.

also tried this: ["preprocess current file" addin for Visual Studio? (C++ )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491254/preprocess-current-file-addin-for-visual-studio-c)

I have adapted the path to `devenv.exe` to match with my install, but I get a warning from Visual Studio, basically an help man.

Am I completely missing something? How get the preprocessed .i files?

Comment: "basically an help man" What's that suppoused to mean? Additionally, in English question marks don't have a space before them in sentences.

Comment: @tambre yes that is probably because I am french, and we prepend a space before them, but I knew that ^^ It means it gives me a prompt explaining how to use the command with all the available options, like an help man.

Comment: I've never heard of whatever you're calling "an help man" - might be a concept exclusive to the French language (Google doesn't give me any results either). You probably mean a "help prompt", which is usually displayed by command-line tools if your command syntax is invalid.

Comment: Go to `Project Properties` ➡ `C/C++` ➡ `Preprocessor` and set `Preprocess to a file` to `Yes`. Rebuild project. Preprocessed files should be saved in `Output directory`.

Comment: @tambre https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page

Comment: @VTT yes that is what I have done, no .i file generated anywhere

Comment: @hymced Oh, you simply meant a man page.

Comment: They should be in `Output directory`, that path to output directory can be found at `Project Properties` ➡ `General` tab.

Comment: @VTT yes here `\$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)`, but they are not, neither Release not Debug :(

Comment: So what is in there instead? Compilation should produce either .obj files (normal) or .i files (preprocessed) for each translation unit.

Comment: I have got 1 .obj for each one of my .cpp, 1 .idb, 1 .pdb, 1 .log

Comment: -_- Please add comments with downvotes

Comment: @hymced - Didn't downvote, but can guess that it comes from the fact that VTT's solution works for everyone else. Change one option to Yes, click Compile, done.

Comment: @Bo I am sorry but it does not work for me. I have a clean install, just made the last update, it does not work, that it. So the spirit here is to downvote when a provided solution does not work ??  that's just great...

Comment: @hymced - Your problem here is that you claim that it doesn't work, but everyone else can easily test the solution (like in my comment) and see that it in fact *does* work. A question with a non-reproducible problem can of course get a few downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

I have not been able to make the preprocessed .i file using the built in option of Visual Studio 2017, but using the command line method it works:

1. open a command prompt of the [Developer Command Prompt for Visual
   Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs)
2. use `cd` to navigate to this location: `$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)`. In my case it is something like that: `C:\Users\UserName\Source\Repos\Project1\Project1`
3. use this command: `CL /P /C Source1.cpp`

Now I get my `Source1.i` next to my source. Thanks all for your very helpful inputs. I will report this on the Visual Studio developer community instead.

Comment: Once you do report it, make sure to link the report in your answer.

Comment: the report is here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/159405/c-unable-to-output-a-preprocessed-file-using-the-p.html

Comment: @hymced Did you faced this error LNK 1104...cannot open file /Debug.xxx.obj like that?